# Silverlight Chart data binding to ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding

I'm not sure if this can be done, but I've got a BubbleSeries with a custom ControlTemplate for the DataPointStyle. I want to add some text to the bubble, but I can't seem to get the data binding working. I want to bind a TextBlock to the "Name" value in the object I've bound to. Hopefully the code should explain:

```
<Style x:Key="BubbleItemTemplate" TargetType="toolkit:BubbleDataPoint">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:BubbleDataPoint">
                    <Viewbox x:Name="viewbox">
                        <Border>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Name}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Viewbox>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

and the ItemSource is

```
public void AddData(List<ChartItem> items)
    {
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> gridData = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        foreach (var i in items)
        {
            gridData.Add(CreateBubbleEntry(i.XAxis, i.YAxis, i.ZAxis, i.Title));
        }
        _bubbleView.ItemsSource = gridData;
    }

    private Dictionary<string, object> CreateBubbleEntry(double independent, double dependent, double size, string title)
    {
        var item = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        item.Add("independent", independent);
        item.Add("dependent", dependent);
        item.Add("size", size);
        item.Add("Name", title);
        return item;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing: `{TemplateBinding Name}` with `{Binding Name}`

That should do the trick.